# form validations in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this this rider model:
rider.ts

```
export class Rider {
name: String;
mobileNumber: Number;
email: String;
password: String;
confirmPassword: String;
gender: String;
city: String;
```

}

The signUp.html :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
   <ion-title>Signup</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content>
 <form id="sign-form"  [formGroup]="signUp" >
  <ion-list>
   <div class="input-box">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Full Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"  formControlName=rider.name></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>

  <div class="input-box">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Mobile Number</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="mobileNumber" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>


  <div class="input-box">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>

  <div class="input-box">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>

  <div class="input-box">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Confirm Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" >
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>

  <div class="input-box">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select interface="popover" class="select-option" 
       formControlName="gender" >
        <ion-option selected>Male</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Female</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </div>


  <div class="input-box">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select interface="popover" class="select-option" 
    formControlName="city" >
        <ion-option selected>NewYork</ion-option>
        <ion-option>London</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Dubai</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </div>



  <div>
    <button ion-button color="primary" block color="secondary" 
  [disabled]="!signUp.valid"(click)="submit()">Sign Up</button>
  </div>

</ion-list>
```

The rider.ts is :

```
          import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { User } from '../../providers/providers'; 
import { MainPage } from '../pages';
import { Rider } from '../../models/rider';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html'
})

export class SignupPage {

  public signUp: FormGroup;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public user: User,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public translateService: TranslateService,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {
      this.signUp = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,]),
      mobileNumber: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10)]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      confirmPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      gender: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   });

    }
  }
}
```

How to connect my rider model to my form input?

How to display the toast message if the use details are wrong and display success in toast message when registration done?

I am new to ionic ..All the tutorials available does not show this..approach.

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick demo of using a Toast message for feedback on form submission and values:

```
public submit() {
  if(this.signUp.valid && this.signUp.value.password === this.signUp.value.confirmPassword) {
    // Create new Rider object and add values
    let rider = new Rider();
    rider.name = this.signUp.value.name;
    rider.mobileNumber = this.signUp.value.mobileNumber;
    rider.email = this.signUp.value.email;
    rider.password = this.signUp.value.password;
    rider.confirmPassword = this.signUp.value.confirmPassword;
    rider.gender = this.signUp.value.gender;
    rider.city = this.signUp.value.city;
    this.showToast('Form valid!!!')
    // Do something with rider...
  } else if(this.signUp.value.password !== this.signUp.value.confirmPassword) {
    this.showToast("Passwords don't match!")
  } else {
    this.showToast('Form invalid')
  } 
}

private showToast(message: string): void {
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: message,
    duration: 5000,
    showCloseButton: true
  });
  toast.present();
}
```

But the else block in `submit()` will never be reached unless you remove the `[disabled]="!signUp.valid"` from the submit button in you HTML template as currently the button will remain disabled until the form is completely valid so an invalid form cannot be submitted.

See [Toast Controller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toast/ToastController/) in Ionic docs for more details on configuring the toast controller.

Hope this helps.

EDIT - Includes very basic password confirmation.

Comment: No probs @108abhishek :-)

Comment: I want to print toast message when user enters wrong email or password does not match..at time of validation ..before submitting the form.. Can you please help with that..

Comment: Hmm that's a bit harder, you'll have to create a custom validator for that I think, an easier alternative would be to add this to the submit button in the HTML template: `[disabled]="signUp.value.password !== signUp.value.confirmPassword"` which will disable the button until the passwords match.

Comment: Actually try what I just posted above.

Comment: yes, that works..I am trying to write custom validator which generates toast messages..

Comment: The problem with the validator is that it will need to reference two input fields so it will need to be at the form level instead I think.